# Not able to convert dates from string in R

Tags: r, date

Please help. Not sure, what i am doing wrong here. But, the below simple code for converting date from character is not working for me in R. It is giving `NA`, instead of any values.

```
x <- c("3-Sep-13","3-Oct-13","10-Nov-2014")
x   
# [1] "3-Sep-13"    "3-Oct-13"    "10-Nov-2014"

class(x)
# [1] "character"

as.Date(x,format="%d-%m-%Y")
# [1] NA NA NA

format(as.Date(x,"%d-%m-%Y"))
# [1] NA NA NA

as.Date(x,format="%Y-%m-%d")
# [1] NA NA NA

format(as.Date(x,"%Y-%m-%d"))
# [1] NA NA NA
```

Comment: See `?strptime`; `%b`.

Comment: In addition to @Henrik's comment, also see `%y` in `?strptime`. Make sure your dates in `x` are consistent in their formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Besides what's already mentioned in comments, your character vector is ambiguous.

```
as.Date(x[1:2], "%d-%b-%y")
[1] "2013-09-03" "2013-10-03"
as.Date(x[3], "%d-%b-%Y")
[1] "2014-11-10"
```

Comment: @user3759240 In that case, you are encouraged to _accept_ the answer by hitting a green tick mark next to it. You may also take a look at your previous questions and do the same there, if possible. You'll receive a small rep bonus for that as well.